# 違う型の同じ数値を比較するときに == と Equals で結果が異なる？

Tags: c#

int型とlong型で同じ数値を比較すると == はtrueを返しますが、Equalsはfalseを返すことがあります。

```
Console.WriteLine("1 == 1L: {0}", 1 == 1L);
Console.WriteLine("1L == 1: {0}", 1L == 1);
Console.WriteLine("1.Equals(1L): {0}", 1.Equals(1L));
Console.WriteLine("1L.Equals(1): {0}", 1L.Equals(1));

// 出力：
//   1 == 1L: True
//   1L == 1: True
//   1.Equals(1L): False
//   1L.Equals(1): True
```

値型では基本的に == と Equals は同じだと思っていたのですが、違うのでしょうか？

また、もしEqualsだけ型を厳密に見ていると仮定すると、trueを返すこともあるのが謎です。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Object.Equals(object)`は型が同じであれば`operator ==(T, T)`の結果を、型が異なれば`false`を返すのが標準的な動作です。
しかし質問文の例ではオーバーロードにより`int`から`long`への暗黙変換が発生しており、コード上の型が一致していません。

最初の二つの式ですが、C#の数値比較は`int`、`uint`、`long`、`ulong`同士の比較しか定義されていないため、`operator ==(long, long)`が選択されます。
また最後についても`IEquatable<T>`の実装である`Int64.Equals(long)`が存在するため、こちらも暗黙変換が発生します。
これらの結果が`False`でないのはそのためです。

Comment: つまり`Int64.Equals(Int64)`の存在しなかった .NET 1.x系では`1L.Equals(1)`も`False`となりそうですね。（試してませんがたぶん）

Comment: @sayuri [旧modern.IEで配布されてる](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/)XPの仮想マシンで試したら、その通りになりました（こういう使い方していいのか怪しいですが） http://i.stack.imgur.com/37pdN.png

Answer (score 10):

等値演算子の`==`に関しては、C# の言語仕様 **7.3.6.2 二項数値上位変換**で規定されている通り、`int`が`long`へ暗黙の型変換されるためにtrueとなります。

他方、Equalsメソッドの呼び出しに関しては、pgrhoさんのご指摘の通りですが、多少補足しますと、`long.Equals(long obj)`と、`long.Equals(object obj)`のどちらが**より適切**であるかは、C#の言語仕様　**7.5.3  オーバーロードの解決法**によって、**より適切な関数メンバ**が解決されていくことになります。

この際、元の`int`は、`long`へも`object`へも暗黙の型変換が許容されていますので、どちらがより適切なのかと言うことになりますが、これは**7.5.3.5 より適切な変換対象**より

> 異なる 2 つの型 T1 と T2 がある場合、次の条件が 1 つでも満たされると、T1 の方が T2 より適切な変換対象です。
>   •   T1 から T2 への暗黙の型変換が存在し、T2 から T1 への暗黙の型変換が存在しない
>   以下略

とのことから、`long`から`object`への暗黙の型変換が存在し、逆に`object`から`long`への暗黙の型変換が存在しないことから、最終的に`long.Equals(long obj)`がより適切な関数メンバと解釈され、適用されるので、

```
Console.WriteLine("1L.Equals(1): {0}", 1L.Equals((long)1));
```

明示的に書くのであれば、このような関数呼び出しなり、引数のi 及び　lが同値で有れば、trueに成るのだと思います。

他方、int.Equalsの場合は、long型からint型への暗黙の型変換は存在せず、逆にlong型からobject型への暗黙の型変換は存在するので、結果的にint.Equals(object obj)が呼ばれFalseに成るのだと思います。